# jQuery datatable column width on edit mode

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable with inline editing functionalities. I am successfully able to define all custom widths for the table, however, as soon as I enter edit mode, the column width expands and the table keeps jumping back and forth. It seems that the view 'sWidth' works fine, and I get the desired column width, but as soon as user presses double click to enter edit mode, the column size expands and squeezes all the other columns. Is this a lingering issue within the actual js code or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                oTable = $("#datatables").dataTable({
                            "aoColumns" : [
                                {
                                    "sName" : "fullName",
                                    "sWidth" : "15%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "location",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "lengthOfStay",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "codeStatus",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "dvt",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "catheter",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "lae",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "lace",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "comments",
                                    "sWidth" : "25%"
                                },
                                {
                                    "sName" : "discharge",
                                    "sClass": "alignCenter"
                                }
                             ],
                            "aaSorting":[[1, "desc"]],
                            "bPaginate": false,
                            "bLengthChange": false,
                            "bFilter": false,
                            "bSort": true,
                            "bInfo": false,
                            "bAutoWidth": false,
                            "sAjaxSource" : 'checklistdataallteam',
                            "sServerMethod": "GET",
                            "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
                                //The call to makeEditable is set here to make sure all the data are loaded 
                                this.makeEditable({
                                    oEditableSettings: { event: 'dblclick' },
                                    sUpdateURL : 'UpdateChecklistData',
                                    aoColumns : [
                                         null,  //patient name; no editing
                                         null,  //location; no editing  
                                         null,  //stay length; no editing
                                         {      //code status; default edit
                                            placeholder: '-'
                                         }, 
                                         {      //dvt; default edit
                                            placeholder: '-',
                                         }, 
                                         {      //catheter, default edit
                                            placeholder: '-',
                                         },
                                         null,  //lae; no editing
                                         null,  //lace; no editing
                                         {      //comment; default editing
                                            placeholder: '-',
                                         }, 
                                         null   //discharge; no editing                                          
                                     ]
                                });
                            }
                   });
        });
```

I am using Jeditable version 1.7.1, Datatables version 1.9.4 and jquery.dataTables.editable.js version 1.1.5

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem may be solved by setting the width attribute to 100% when the jeditable function for the datatable is initialized.  See here:
[DataTable Column resizes on edit](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7950/an-editable-column-via-jeditable-resizes-gets-wider-on-clicking-in-another-cell-in-the-same-column/p1)

That link refers to the editable demo, and when you view the code on that [page](http://datatables.net/beta/1.9/examples/api/editable.html), you can see how the width attribute is used.